# Maintaining a countdown clock upon program termination

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am learning to program in C# for .Net using VS2015 Community Ed.

*Its my first question so if I am not in the correct format I apologize.*

At present I am trying to click a button and have the program begin a countdown. This countdown item should be named (ie..Timer1) and its name appear in a `ComboBox`. That part is the easy part. The part where I am having an issue is figuring out how to have the timer continue if the program is terminated.

Is there a way to keep the countdown running after program termination until specifically terminated by the user? If so, What should I be searching for in order to learn this?

Comment: `how to have the timer continue if the program is terminated.`  That's not possible.  You probably want to "delay" the termination until your counter is at zero.  Show your code of what you attempted.

Comment: You can't continue code after the application containing the code terminates. If the timer is created in your application, and your application terminates, the timer is destroyed. Period. End of story.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it resident like the "TSR (Terminate Stay Resident)" programs of the past? If not, is there an event for when the program is terminated that I can trigger an event from before the program actually ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide your form but the timer still continue, but there is no space for the timer to run if you close the application.  It has to live in an application.  I think what you're probably looking for is it living longer than your form, that is possible, just move the timer's scope up higher than the form, you'll have to play with the Program class, maybe make the form modeless instead of modal, or maybe not.  You'll have to try a few ways.  But the timer will have to run in your application, everything in your application dies when the application does.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have your timer continue to run after your process exits is to launch a separate process in which the timer will run.  Of course, the original process will no longer have access to the timer, so you'll need to use some form of interprocess communication to allow the timer process to inform the original process of the timer state.